# How to get values from dictionary in jinja when key is a variable?

Tags: python, variables, dictionary, jinja2, substitution

I'm trying to retrieve entries from a python dictionary in jinja2, but the problem is I don't know what key I want to access ahead of time - the key is stored in a variable called `s.course`. So my problem is I need to double-substitute this variable. I don't want to use a `for` loop because that will go through the dictionary way more than is necessary. Here's a workaround that I created, but it's possible that the `s.course` values could change so obviously hard-coding them like this is bad. I want it to work essentially like this:

```
{% if s.course == "p11" %}
    {{course_codes.p11}}
{% elif s.course == "m12a" %}
    {{course_codes.m12a}}
{% elif s.course == "m12b" %}
    {{course_codes.m12b}}
{% endif %}
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
{{course_codes.{{s.course}}}}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why isn't an actual object representing the relevant course codes being passed to the template?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `course_codes.get(s.course)`:

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> env = jinja2.Environment()
>>> t = env.from_string('{{ codes.get(mycode) }}')
>>> t.generate(codes={'a': '123'}, mycode='a').next()
u'123'
```

Comment: This is returning an error `Could not parse the remainder: '('a')' from 'codes.get('a')'`. 
Not even `{{course_codes[s.course]}}` is working for me.

Comment: even i got the same,may i know how did u solve this ?

Answer (score 17):

There is no need to use the dot notation at all, you can do:

```
"{{course_codes[s.course]}}"
```

Comment: when i try to use like above it returning Could not parse the remainder: '[s.sample_type]' from 'samType[s.sample_type]'

Answer (score 7):

I'm using Jinja with Salt, and I've found that something like the following works well:

```
{% for role in pillar.packages %}
  {% for package in pillar['packages'][role] %}
    install_{{ package }}:
      pkg.installed:
        - name: {{ package }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

That is, use the more verbose `[ ]` syntax and leave the quotes out when you need to use a variable.