# Using jinja variable as dictionary key

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, jinja2

I'm making a django app to do with tests/exams. Two of the models in this app are the "Question" and "Answer" model which have a one-to-many relationship. On the page, each question will be listed with all of its possible answers below it which the user can choose from.

In my `views.py` file, after getting the list of question objects, the best way I thought of for storing the answers was in a dictionary like so:

```python
answers = {}
for question in questions:
    answers[question.id] = Answer.objects.filter(question=question.id)
```

Then, for the template, I thought I would be able to do something like:

```html
{% for question in questions %}
<h2>{{ question.title }}</h2>
<ul>
    {% for answer in answers.{{ question.id }} %}
    <li>{{ answer.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

The error arises in this line - `{% for answer in answers.{{ question.id }} %}`.

I've tried rewriting this line as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830393/how-to-get-values-from-dictionary-in-jinja-when-key-is-a-variable) which suggested things like:

```
{% for answer in answers[question.id] %}
```

and

```
{% for answer in answers.get(question.id) %}
```

but none of these worked.

Please let me know if there is a syntax in Jinja that allows this or else if there is a better way of me passing the `answers` variable in my `views.py` file altogether.

Comment: I'm confused, if they have a relationship shouldn't you be able to do {% for answer in question.answer_set.all %}? Or define a related_name in the Answer model so you can do just question.answers.all

Comment: Mabe this will help? [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57821896/access-dictionary-within-dictionary-jinja)

Comment: @JonasGrumann. The question.answer_set.all worked, I didn't know this was possible, thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked, I added it as a proper answer with a little more explanation on the related_name, I'd be glad if you could accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the _set.all() convention to get all the related items:

```
{% for answer in question.answer_set.all %}
    {{ answer.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

This works, but if you want to have a more readable version you can define a `related_name` in your model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    prompt = (models.CharField)

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name="answers")
    correct = models.BooleanField()
    prompt = models.CharField()
```

And then you can use that related name instead of the `_set`:

```
{% for answer in question.answers.all %}
    {{ answer.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

which makes it a bit more readable.